# Public Bug Tracking and Version Control System

Tags: looking-for-a-script, bugs, git, subversion

We're in the process of moving out of a private beta into our live version of the site.

We're trying to find a good Bug Tracking System + Version Control system. Our CEO has requested that the new system be able to do the following things and I can't figure out where I can do this:

- Public facing Bug Tracker - Guests **don't** need to register to post OR ability to sync with current user tables to allow SSO.
- Ability to assign developers to posted bugs
- Integration with Version Control to allow Developers to attach bug to build version to confirm when the bug is fixed.
- Miscellaneous Project Management - Ability to create projects/tasks and assign them to developers or other administrative teams.

We are moving away from TeamBox.com as our Project Management suite as it just wasn't development oriented as we needed and we currently have no Version Control system.

Much thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks to me like your requirements are the same as any software project. Can you convince me that you need something specific where your end product is a site rather than a bit of software? Otherwise I'll flag this for migration to Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Shameless self promotion, but I asked this question over at StackOverflow a couple of years ago ["Does anyone know of a decent free online bug tracker for web development purposes?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966404/does-anyone-know-of-a-decent-free-online-bug-tracker-for-web-development-purpose)